# Selecting unique items from combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given a list of combinations (not permutations), how many do I need to randomly select to ensure $m$ unique items?

For example, given combinations of $3$ letters, if I want $6$ unique items then it *could* be accomplished with 2 combinations:

```
ABC
DEF
```

which gives me 6 unique letters - $ABCDEF$. But given I'm randomly selecting combinations, I could have also selected:

```
ABC
ABD
ABE
CDE
CDA
CDB
...
```

Here I've selected $6$ combinations but so far only have 5 unique items: $ABCDE$

So how many combinations would I need to select to ensure 6 unique letters?

---

I'll be making sure not to select the same combination twice, so there'll no complication of selecting $ABC$ 6 times!

My actual problem involves selecting 20 unique items from groups of 6, but it'd be nice to have a general formula.

*(Note I'm **not** a mathematician just a lowly computer programmer, so simple formulas and layman answers would be appreciated!)*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Combinations are subsets.  To ensure $n$ unique items, you must select from a set with at least $n$ elements.  The set $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ has $\binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!2!} = 10$ subsets.  They are $$\{A, B, C\}, \{A, B, D\}, \{A, B, E\}, \{A, C, D\}, \{A, C, E\}, \{A, D, E\}, \{B,C,D\}, \{B,C,E\}, \{B,D,E\}, \{C,D,E\}$$  A set with six elements has $\binom{6}{3} = \frac{6!}{3!3!} = 20$ subsets.  Perhaps the answer you had in mind for this example is $11$ since you would need at least six elements in the set to produce $11$ three-element subsets.

Comment: If you are selecting combinations at random, you can never be certain that you will have a complete set of items.  For example, it's possible, although not likely, that you might select ABC in your example every time.

Comment: @awkward: That depends on whether the random selection is carried out with or without replacement.

Comment: Good point @awkward, but I can (and do) make sure not to select the same combination twice. I'd just like to know how many I should select to ensure $x$ unique items. (Question updated.)

Comment: as @N.F.Taussig pointed out, if your base set has $N$ elements, and you want you have a set of combinations of $m$ elements and you want to make sure you have a total of $n$ elements you need to select $\binom{n-1}{m} + 1$ combinations.

Comment: @JohnC: The command for binomial coefficients is `\binom#1#2`. You can also look at how a certain formatting was produced by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show Math As > TeX Commands".

Comment: thanks @joriki, good thing this isn't tex.stackexchange, that would be embarrasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to have been given by `@N.F.Taussig` in the question comments and formalised by `@John C`.

To guarantee $m$ unique letters from groups of $n$, I need to select $\binom{n-1}{m} + 1$ combinations.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) explains this notation to be: $\binom{g}{k} = \frac{g!}{k!(g-k)!}$

So to answer the example with $n=6$ and $m=3$:

$\binom{n-1}{m} = \binom{6-1}{3} = \binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = \frac{5!}{3!\times2!} = \frac{5\times4\times3\times2\times1}{(3\times2\times1)\times(2\times1)} = \frac{5\times4}{2\times1}$

$\binom{n-1}{m} + 1 = \frac{20}{2}+1 = 11$

---

And for my own real world use with $n=20$ and $m=6$:

$\binom{n-1}{m} = \binom{20-1}{6} = \binom{19}{6} = \frac{19!}{6!(19-6)!} = \frac{19!}{6!\times13!} = \frac{19\times18\times17\times16\times15\times14}{6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1} = \frac{19,535,040}{720}$

$\binom{n-1}{m} + 1 = 27,132+1 = 27,133$

Which I must admit, is a heck of lot bigger than I expected!